# How to set Firefox referrer to "no-referrer" using PHP Referrer-Policy?

Tags: php, firefox, referrer, referrer-policy

Setting referrer on Chrome using this PHP header will set all page referrers to `none/no-referrer: "Referrer-Policy" => "no-referrer"`

I have a problem to set the same Referrer policy to "no-referrer" on Firefox, because seems the same PHP header doesn't work.

The solution must be in PHP, I cannot accept solution through META tags or JS.

```
( "Referrer-Policy" => "no-referrer" )
```

This should set referrer to none, empty on Firefox, but it doesn't.

On Chrome it works without any problem.

Comment: Which version of Firefox do you use?

Comment: I am using the latest version: 65.0

Answer (score 4):

> ( "Referrer-Policy" => "no-referrer" )

This is not a valid [PHP HTML Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

The PHP `header()` functions contain a *text string* of "`<Header>:<value>`" format so;

```
header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer");
```

This will set the header correctly, however depending on your server setup this may be ommitted if the same header has already been set elsewhere, such as in `httpd.conf` on Apache, or if the Header has been set elsewhere with the *always* keywords, such as in `.htaccess` on Apache.

Comment: The code I sent you is actually from our lighttpd config, its adding header to set referrer policy to no referrer for Chrome, but for FireFox it doesnt work.
Same goes for: header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer");
Its setting referrer for Chrome but FireFox doesnt react to referrer changes.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not actual for its author, but I`ll add an answer for the newest visitors:

the "Referrer-Policy" header did not work via PHP (modern virtual hosting), but it works fine if added to .htaccess file.
The syntax is:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
</IfModule>
```