# Referrer-Policy with PHP and htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

is there any way to overwrite the header referrer policy using htaccess or PHP?

HTML Code :

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

Is any way to do same with htaccess or PHP? i tried these code from [How to set Firefox referrer to "no-referrer" using PHP Referrer-Policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509126/how-to-set-firefox-referrer-to-no-referrer-using-php-referrer-policy)

I tried (PHP) :

```
header("Referrer-Policy: origin");
```

With Htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "origin"
</IfModule>
```

Still it not overriding strict-origin-when-cross-origin.

Firefox info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in private browser and it worked !!

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "origin"
</IfModule>
```